# Getting column data in an EntityFramework Join statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm using the EntityFramework (for the first time) and have managed to get as far as querying, updating etc. I've got a linq query that is joining three tables, like so:

```
//get a list of completed orders between the last run date of this job and NOW
        var completedOrders = from orders in db.orders
                              join orderStatus in db.orderStatus
                              on orders.statusID equals orderStatus.statusID
                              join aspnetUsers in db.aspnet_Users
                              on orders.userID equals aspnetUsers.UserId
                              into joined
                              where (orderStatus.statusID == 2 || orderStatus.statusID == 3 || orderStatus.statusID == 5) && (orders.dateTimeStamp > job.lastRunDate && orders.dateTimeStamp < DateTime.Now || !job.lastRunDate.HasValue)
                              select joined;
```

Then I've got a simply foreach loop:

```
foreach (var order in completedOrders)
        {

            //process here
        }
```

My question is, how do I get at the information within the foreach loop? I need to get at the column data, something like:

order["date"]

Although ideally i'd like it to be strongly typed seeing as Im using the Entity Framework.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Al

Comment: You could get all the property with DOT notations. for example 
order.propertyName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `into` and add an anonymous type:

```
...
on orders.userID equals aspnetUsers.UserId
where (orderStatus.statusID == 2 || orderStatus.statusID == 3 || orderStatus.statusID == 5) && (orders.dateTimeStamp > job.lastRunDate && orders.dateTimeStamp < DateTime.Now || !job.lastRunDate.HasValue)
select new { orders, orderStatus, aspnetUsers }
```

Then you can loop through the result

```
 foreach (var x in completedOrders)
 {
   // use x.orders.Date, etc.
 }
```